# @Path in rest-easy with variable?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using rest-easy and I want my `@Path` annotation to obtain it's value from a variable (mayabe a system parameter).

Eg:

```
@Path(someVar)
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String retrieve() {
}
```

I tried reading and got to know that Path must be a constant value.

Is something like above possible in rest easy ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations are processed on compile time. You cannot use a variable as an annotation parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable value in URL, something like below example
so your URL will be /book/some_isbn_code and the getBook method will receive isbn value in id field.

```
@Path("/book/{isbn}")
public String getBook(@PathParam("isbn") String id) {
```

Comment: This is using path value as a variable in the method. What I want is to set path value from a variable

Comment: These URL mapped during application startup so I doubt that you can modify once URL mapped. You can change base URL in web.xml where you map the REST servlet.